# How can I downsample app's screen resolution?

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm running a WebView with a resolution of 1366x768 on my mobile app. And its currently running quite laggy.

Is there any way to "downsample", the screen or the rendering? Or something like that probably, that would allow the webview to run faster instead of setting the webiew res to anything lower?

Like, there are some settings in the "game engines" I used to use in past, which allowed to set a resolution of the game or its screen it would run on. Sure it would look pixelated, but any matter of pixelation or quality is not an issue for me for my current tests.

If my question isn't clear, do let me know. Thank you for any comments or answers.